# Automate Microsoft’s authentication needing a certificate using selenium in a pipeline?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver.io, ms-azure

I am trying to run some scripts in a website using **webdriverio**, this site uses **Microsoft’s** login **authentication** in order to access the website, in my **local** it usually asks me to login not only with credentials but also with **windows hello**, select a certificate. I managed to bypass this screen by:

1. Creating a **registry key** to **autoselect the certificate** for chrome
2. Manually creating and using a previously **authenticated cookie** attached to the driver prior execution (probably not a good solution)

However, I am trying to make this work in an **pipeline** not only in my local. Any ideas on how to handle **Microsoft’s** **authentication** via **backend** to also work remotely?